# How customise Slider blue line in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, slider, swiftui

Like in `UISlider`

```
let slider = UISlider()

slider.minimumTrackTintColor = .red
```

Comment: I don't understand the close votes on this question. It's a perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of Apple's 2021 platforms, you can use the `tint` modifier to change the color of the track to the left of the slider knob. Beyond that, SwiftUI's `Slider` doesn't let you customize its appearance.

If you need more customization, then for now your only option is to create a `UISlider` and wrap it in a `UIViewRepresentable`. Work through [the “Interfacing with UIKit” tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit) and watch [WWDC 2019 Session 231: Integrating SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/231/) to learn how to use `UIViewRepresentable`.

[The `Slider` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/slider#see-also) formerly mentioned a type named `SliderStyle`, but there is no documentation for `SliderStyle` and the type is not actually defined in the public interface of the SwiftUI framework as of Xcode 11 beta 4. It is possible that it will appear in a later release. It is also possible that we will have to wait for a future (after 13) version of SwiftUI for this ability.

If `SliderStyle` does appear, it might allow you to customize the appearance of a `Slider` in the same way that [`ButtonStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/buttonstyle) lets you customize the appearance of `Button`—by assuming total responsibility for drawing it. So you might want to look for `ButtonStyle` tutorials on the net if you want to get a head start.

But `SliderStyle` might end up being more like [`TextFieldStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfieldstyle). Apple provides a small number of `TextFieldStyle`s for you to choose from, but you cannot define your own.

Comment: .accentColor(.red)

Comment: For TextFieldStyle, the private API is `struct MyTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle { func _body(configuration: TextField<_Label>) -> some View { configuration.foregroundColor(.red) } }`. Source (and thanks!):  https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/02/26/textfield-in-swiftui/. Reminder: this is the private/internal/undocumented API, liable to break or cause other issues in the future.

Answer (score 39):

As pointed out in other answers you have limited ability to customize a `Slider` in SwiftUI. You can change the `.accentColor(.red)` but that only changes the [minimumTrackTintColor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uislider/1621348-minimumtracktintcolor).

Example of a `Slider` with `.accentColor(.red)`

[image]

Additionally, you can't change other things like [thumbTintColor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uislider/1621332-thumbtintcolor).
If you want more customization than just `minimumTrackTintColor` that you have no choice but to use a `UISlider` in `SwiftUI` as [rob mayoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57103138/7245977) stated.

Here is some code on how you can use a `UISlider` in SwiftUI

```
struct SwiftUISlider: UIViewRepresentable {

  final class Coordinator: NSObject {
    // The class property value is a binding: It’s a reference to the SwiftUISlider
    // value, which receives a reference to a @State variable value in ContentView.
    var value: Binding<Double>

    // Create the binding when you initialize the Coordinator
    init(value: Binding<Double>) {
      self.value = value
    }

    // Create a valueChanged(_:) action
    @objc func valueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
      self.value.wrappedValue = Double(sender.value)
    }
  }

  var thumbColor: UIColor = .white
  var minTrackColor: UIColor?
  var maxTrackColor: UIColor?

  @Binding var value: Double

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UISlider {
    let slider = UISlider(frame: .zero)
    slider.thumbTintColor = thumbColor
    slider.minimumTrackTintColor = minTrackColor
    slider.maximumTrackTintColor = maxTrackColor
    slider.value = Float(value)

    slider.addTarget(
      context.coordinator,
      action: #selector(Coordinator.valueChanged(_:)),
      for: .valueChanged
    )

    return slider
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISlider, context: Context) {
    // Coordinating data between UIView and SwiftUI view
    uiView.value = Float(self.value)
  }

  func makeCoordinator() -> SwiftUISlider.Coordinator {
    Coordinator(value: $value)
  }
}

#if DEBUG
struct SwiftUISlider_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    SwiftUISlider(
      thumbColor: .white,
      minTrackColor: .blue,
      maxTrackColor: .green,
      value: .constant(0.5)
    )
  }
}
#endif
```

Then you can use this slider in your `ContentView` like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var sliderValue: Double = 0.5

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("SliderValue: \(sliderValue)")
      // Slider(value: $sliderValue).accentColor(.red).padding(.horizontal)

      SwiftUISlider(
        thumbColor: .green,
        minTrackColor: .red,
        maxTrackColor: .blue,
        value: $sliderValue
      ).padding(.horizontal)
    }
  }
}
```

Example:

[image]

[Link to full project](https://github.com/dtroupe18/UISlider-In-SwiftUI)

Comment: `.accentColor(.red)` has no effect in my macOS project (Xcode 12.2 beta 4, macOS 11 RC).

Comment: How do i change the height of the slider line?

Answer (score 12):

```
.accentColor(.red)
```

This will work on iOS and Mac Catalyst.
Check out customizable sliders example [here](https://github.com/spacenation/swiftui-sliders)

Comment: Project will find now under these link: https://github.com/spacenation/swiftui-sliders

Answer (score 4):

If the bright white slider handle grates on your dark mode design, you can use .label color and .softLight to tell it to simmer down. It looks good only in grayscale, unless you can figure out the blend modes and hue rotation.

The best looking result would be from an overlaid shaped with .blendMode(.sourceAtop)... but that blocks interaction, sadly.

```swift
@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

var body: some View {

        let hackySliderBGColor: Color = colorScheme == .dark ? Color(.secondarySystemBackground) : Color(.systemBackground)
        let hackySliderAccentColor: Color = colorScheme == .dark ? Color(.label) : Color(.systemGray2)
        let hackySliderBlendMode: BlendMode = colorScheme == .dark ? .softLight : .multiply

...

    ZStack {
            Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(hackySliderBGColor)

// This second Rect prevents a white sliver if slider is at max value.
             .overlay(Rectangle()
                  .foregroundColor(hackySliderBGColor)
                  .offset(x: 5)
             )

            Slider(value: $pointsToScoreLimit, 
                   in: themin...themax, step: 5)
            .accentColor(hackySliderAccentColor)
            .blendMode(hackySliderBlendMode)
    }
```

Example:
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Answer (score 3):

You can change the maximum track color using `ZStack` like this

```swift
var body: some View {
  VStack {
    Spacer()
    Image("Fun").resizable().frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center).cornerRadius(20)
    ZStack {
      Rectangle()
        .frame(height: 2)
        .foregroundColor(.yellow).frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 150)
      Slider(value: $sliderval, in: 0...timeSlider_maximumValue, label: {Text("PLayer")}, minimumValueLabel: {Text("\(timeSlider_minimumValue)")}, maximumValueLabel: {Text("\(timeSlider_maximumValuetext)")}) { success in
        SilderTap()
      }.padding(.horizontal).tint(.green).foregroundColor(.white)
    }
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp7q6.png)

Answer (score 2):

So I tried to use `.accentColor(.red)` without success, so I noticed that for newer versions one has to use `.tint(.red)` to make the changes visible.

Hope this helps.