# Changing the thumb image of the slider conditionally in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, slider

I've been looking ways to change my thumb image of the slider conditionally for every value change. Since I was not able to find ways to locate the thumb, I used customised slider, using this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57101754/how-customise-slider-blue-line-in-swiftui). It works perfectly fine, however, I'm not sure how to change the thumb image conditionally.
Please help.

Pretty new to SwiftUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use slider method,

```
setThumbImage(image, for: .normal)
setThumbImage(image, for: . highlighted)
```

And as per your requirement if you want to change image on value change you need to add your code like (code is from your attached link sample),

```
@objc func valueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
      self.value.wrappedValue = Double(sender.value)
      let arra: [UIImage?] = [UIImage(systemName: "heart"), UIImage(systemName: "pencil"), UIImage(systemName: "trash")]
      
      sender.setThumbImage(arra.randomElement() as? UIImage, for: .normal)
      sender.setThumbImage(arra.randomElement() as? UIImage, for: .highlighted)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That really worked, however, I'm not sure how to change the image on the value change of 1 (Step = 10). It changes so rapidly. 

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: use mySlider.isContinuous = false, This way you will receive valueChanged event only when the user stops moving the slider.

Comment: more details answer is here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390298/iphone-how-to-detect-the-end-of-slider-drag

Comment: Thankyou since i didn't get the chance to say thanks then