# Changing Slider thumb in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, slider, uislider

is it possible to change the thumb of a Slider in SwiftUI like you can with a UISlider in UIKit? With a UISlider all you have to do is:
`self.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "Play_black"), for: .normal)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How customise Slider blue line in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57101754/how-customise-slider-blue-line-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect).

You are basically just accessing the underlying `UISlider` from SwiftUI's `Slider`, and then setting it there. This is much easier than creating a custom slider or making a representable.

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var value: Double = 0

    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: $value)
            .introspectSlider { slider in
                slider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "Play_black"), for: .normal)
            }
    }
}
```

Result (temporary image):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using UIKit's `appearance` in SwiftUI.

Example:

```
struct CustomSlider : View {
    @State private var value : Double = 0
    init() {
        let thumbImage = UIImage(systemName: "circle.fill")
        UISlider.appearance().setThumbImage(thumbImage, for: .normal)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: $value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is awesome! A great solution that avoids using a third-party framework or building a custom slider from scratch. Thank you!

Comment: Does this actually work? I see the `onAppear` solution works, but not this one.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same thing in iOS 16. The simplest way to customize it is with the **.onAppear** modifier:

```swift
Slider(value: $value)
    .onAppear {
        let thumbImage = UIImage(systemName: "circle.fill")
        UISlider.appearance().setThumbImage(thumbImage, for: .normal)
    }
```

Inspired by: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/719658

*Update based on soundflix's comment*

**WARNING: this changes all sliders in the same view!!!**

To be more clear, if you have a **SampleView** that contains this .onAppear code, the **SampleView** will ***pollute*** any view that contains **SampleView** (and any **upstream** and **downstream** views as well!), so be ***very careful*** with this solution if you want multiple slider styles in your app!

If you still want to use this code after understanding its limitations, you might want to move the .onAppear to the outer-most view to reflect what it does more accurately, like so:

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("\(value1)")
        Slider(value: $value1)
        Text("\(value2)")
        Slider(value: $value2)
     }
    .onAppear {
        let thumbImage = UIImage(systemName: "circle.fill")
        UISlider.appearance().setThumbImage(thumbImage, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that this solution **changes all `Slider` views** in your app.

Comment: I just did a test; you are partially correct. This code, unfortunately, changes all controls appearing in the same view, meaning if you have multiple sliders with different styles and put them in a view, whoever appears first will be the style of the slider in that view. Each view can have its own style, though.

Comment: In my testing there's always exactly one thumpImage for all sliders, no matter where and how many `onAppear` I declare in child/parent/grandparent views.

Comment: Thanks ```soundflix```; I have now modified my answer with more clarity. This ```.onAppear``` will pollute an entire view hierarchy for sure (as you said child/parent/grandparent, etc.); however, if you have a view hierarchy that is not polluted by this ```.onAppear``` already, you can start a different pollution within it by creating a different slider style. I do hope to find a native solution to not having this polluting behaviour, though...